Remove last row/column/... of an arbritary N dimensional array
I am using numpy meshgrid to produce a set of coordinate grids which are slices of a bigger meshgrid. The thing is, the number of dimensions of the meshgrid is arbitrary. Therefore, say, for a 2D meshgrid it would be X[0][:-1,:-1] X[1][:-1,:-1] and if the meshgrid was 3D iit would be requiered X[0][:-1,:-1,:-1] etc. I think I would be able to create a for loop to do this or something but I was wondering if there was a simpler way.
Thank you.

You can index with a tuple which you construct with ordinary python means.  e.g. idx=tuple([slice(None,-1) for _ in range(3)])

Instead of a for loop you could let Numpy handle the first dimension. Like so:
import numpy as np

x = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))

slice_ = (...,) + (slice(0, -1),) * len(x)

x = list(np.array(x)[slice_])
print(x)

However a list comprehension is probably just fine:
import numpy as np

x = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))

slice_ = (slice(0, -1),) * len(x)

x = [_[slice_] for _ in x]

This number of dimension is always small compared to the size of the array. So the for loop will never become the bottleneck.
I hope this helps!
